# Why are the angles calculated in c++ not accurate?

Tags: c++, trigonometry, angle

I wanted to write a turtle in c++, but the angles at the turn are not accurate.

I tried to create a Koch curve, but the result was [bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrEbp.png)

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efWmi.png)is a larger picture of this, it looks like the angles are wrong

This is my program:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "turtle.h"

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
#define HIBA_00 TEXT("Error:Program initialisation process.")

HINSTANCE hInstGlob;
int OwniCmdShow;
char szClassName[] = "WindowsApp";
HWND Form1;
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc0(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

RECT rc;
HDC hdcMem;
HBITMAP hbmMem, hbmOld;
HBRUSH hbrBkGnd;
HDC hdc;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;

void DB_prepare_puffer(void);
void DB_start_drawing(void);
void DB_end_drawing(void);


void draw(void);
void screen_clear(void);
void print(int n);


int depth = 4;
float length = 1000;
turtle t;



int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("StdWinClassName");
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS wndclass0;
    OwniCmdShow = iCmdShow;
    hInstGlob = hInstance;

    wndclass0.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass0.lpfnWndProc = WndProc0;
    wndclass0.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass0.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass0.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndclass0.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass0.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass0.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass0.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndclass0.lpszClassName = TEXT("WIN0");

    if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass0))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, HIBA_00, TEXT("Program Start"), MB_ICONERROR); return 0;
    }

    Form1 = CreateWindow(TEXT("WIN0"),
        TEXT("Form1"),
        (WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_MINIMIZEBOX),
        0,
        0,
        1920,
        1050,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);
    DB_prepare_puffer();

    ShowWindow(Form1, OwniCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(Form1);
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc0(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hdc_lokal;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps_lokal;

    switch (message) {
    case WM_CREATE:
        break;
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        break;
    case WM_ERASEBKGND:
        return (LRESULT)1;
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc_lokal = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps_lokal);
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps_lokal);
        t.init();
        draw();
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void DB_prepare_puffer(void)
{
    GetClientRect(Form1, &rc);
    hdc = GetDC(Form1);
    hbmMem = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);
}

void DB_start_drawing(void)
{
    GetClientRect(Form1, &rc);
    hdc = GetDC(Form1);
    BeginPaint(Form1, &ps);
    hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    hbmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmMem);
    hbrBkGnd = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));
    FillRect(hdcMem, &rc, hbrBkGnd);
    DeleteObject(hbrBkGnd);
}

void DB_end_drawing(void)
{
    BitBlt(hdc, rc.left, rc.top, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmOld);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);
    EndPaint(Form1, &ps);
}

void draw(void)
{
    DB_start_drawing();
    screen_clear();
    int i = 0;
    depth = 5;
    length = 1200;
    while (i < depth) {
        length = length / 3;
        i++;
    }
    t.right(270);
    print(depth);
    DB_end_drawing();
}
//************************
//clear screen
//************************
void screen_clear(void)
{
    HBRUSH hBrush;
    RECT rect;
    HDC hdc;
    hdc = hdcMem;
    hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));
    SelectObject(hdc, hBrush);
    SetRect(&rect, 0, 0, 1500, 900);
    FillRect(hdc, &rect, hBrush);
    DeleteObject(hBrush);
}
void print(int m) {
    int n = m;
    if (n == 0) {
        t.forward(length, hdcMem);
    }
    if (n != 0){
        n -= 1;
        print(n);
        t.left(60);
        print(n);
        t.right(120);
        print(n);
        t.left(60);
        print(n);
    }
}
```

this is the turtle.h file:

```
#pragma once
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include "resource.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <cmath>

class turtle {
public:
    void init();
    void right(double _angle);
    void left(double _angle);
    void forward(int distance, HDC hdc);
    double angle = 0;
    POINT pos;
protected:
private:
};
```

And this is the turtle.cpp:

```
#pragma once
#include "turtle.h"

void turtle::init()
{
    pos.x = 40;
    pos.y = 800;
    angle = 0;
}
void turtle::left(double _angle) {
    angle -= _angle;
}
void turtle::right(double _angle) {
    angle += _angle;
}
void turtle::forward(int distance, HDC hdc) {
    MoveToEx(hdc, pos.x, pos.y, NULL);
    double cos_angle = cos(angle * M_PI / (double)180);
    double sin_angle = sin(angle * M_PI / (double)180);
    POINT endpoint;
    endpoint.x = (0 - (double)distance * sin_angle) + pos.x;
    endpoint.y = (0 + (double)distance * cos_angle) + pos.y;
    LineTo(hdc, endpoint.x, endpoint.y);
    pos = endpoint;
}
```

In Python, however, this code worked (essentially the same as the c++ code):

```
from turtle import *

color('blue', 'white')
speed(100000000)
penup()
back(600)
pendown()
begin_fill()
depth = 0
length = 300
i = 0

def print(n):
    if n == 0:
        forward(length )
    if n != 0:
        n -= 1
        print(n)
        left(60)
        print(n)
        right(120)
        print(n)
        left(60)
        print(n)


i = 0
depth = 5
length = 300
while i < depth:
    length = length / 3
    i += 1

print(depth)
```

([Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQ4ry.png))

I hope you can help me.
Thanks

Comment: why is the output bad?

Comment: Is there a radians/degrees issue in the angles? I see the conversion to radian before the trig functions are called, is there any reverting to degrees needed anywhere? Also `length = length / 3;` results in a `float` value where you use `double` later. Not sure if the loss of precision impacts the results anywhere.

Comment: Judging from the picture, it is not the angles which are incorrect, but the length of the lines that are drawn are inconsistent. The third line from the left is obviously shorter than the second one. Check the rounding rules in your C code.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The right part should be more "alligned" with the left one.

Comment: It might be easier to spot the difference visually (and to debug it) with fewer iterations, but in every `_/\_` section, the right side of the peak is shorter than the left one.

Comment: You are using `int distance` as a parameter, shouldn't it and all the coordinates be `double`?

Comment: &Bob I changed the type of the 'pos' and 'endpoint' variables to 'double'. And it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work with this code because the previously calculated position is stored more accurately.
turtle.cpp:

```
#pragma once
#include "turtle.h"

void turtle::init()
{
    pos.x = 40;
    pos.y = 800;
    angle = 0;
}
void turtle::left(double _angle) {
   angle -= _angle;
 }
void turtle::right(double _angle) {
    angle += _angle;
}
void turtle::forward(double distance, HDC hdc) {
    MoveToEx(hdc, pos.x, pos.y, NULL);
    double cos_angle = cos(angle * M_PI / (double)180);
    double sin_angle = sin(angle * M_PI / (double)180);
    DPOINT endpoint;
    endpoint.x = (0 - distance * sin_angle) + pos.x;
    endpoint.y = (0 + distance * cos_angle) + pos.y;
    LineTo(hdc, endpoint.x, endpoint.y);
    pos = endpoint;
}
```

And insert this code to turtle.h:
`

```
typedef struct DPOINT {
    double x;
    double y;
};
```

`

And change the 'pos' variable type to 'DPOINT'